# Removing field indexes safely

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm moving the data model of an app engine app to Objectify, and I've noticed that Objectify for it's entities specifies all properties of an entity as unindexed by default, which makes sense to me as it would be quicker on writes and less space would be used up.

But the GAE default (at least when I wrote the app) is to create field endexes on all fields by default, so all my fields are indexed. And there is hundreds of thousands of rows.

I really only need only a small fraction of these fields indexed and I would like to set them as unindexed. I want to set these fields as @Unindexed in objectify, but how can I remove the indexed data already in the datastore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add or remove single-property indexes, change the metadata (add/remove @Index and @Unindex) and then load+save the entities. You may wish to use map/reduce for this.

Comment: So there is no way to "vacuum" these indexes?

Comment: Other than load/save each individual entity, no.

Comment: What a pain. It would be so nice to have a delete button on each index! But I guess that's not gonna happen for whatever reason. It's pretty easy to vacuum your custom indices. Shame it's so hard to do it for the property indices...

Comment: So if I was to specify a property as @Unindexed now after not specifying previously and  then persist a new row.. Would that new row property value be unindexed? Or would it be still indexed because all the existing rows are indexed?

Comment: Single-property indexes (ie @Index/@Unindex) are on a per-entity basis. If you save it with an index, it has an index. The annotation merely controls behavior when the entity is saved. See GAE javadocs for Entity.setProperty() and Entity.setUnindexedProperty()